# Ubuntu One will not sync a file over 100MB (evolution backup tar.gz)

Tags: ubuntu-one

It just says "File Sync in progress" and it doesn't change and other files are not getting backed up.  If I disconnect, delete (and from the trash) the file in question, the backup eventually completes when all is uploaded.

This is a problem because I like to take a weekly backup of my email and keep the last two....

Thanks

Comment: According to the [Ubuntu One FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhatIsTheLargestSizeFileICanSync), 5GB should be the maximum supported individual file size you can sync. It is also a known issue that [many files can take a long time to sync](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyIsItTakingSoLongForMyFilesToSync), and this in the process of being worked on.

Comment: what does your overall usage of Ubuntu One look like? Are you just using the free 2GB plan, or are you paying for more space? Also, how much of that space are you currently using?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).